# Where can I find a collection of proven deep learning architectures?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning

I am trying to get some intuition on how to architect neural networks to solve various problems. I am hoping to study known, proven architectures.

For example, I know that for image classification, a good example is the VGG-16 network.

Where can I find a large collection of network architectures that span a diverse range of problems?

Answer (score 3):

For image classification, VGG is a bit out-dated compared to more recent models such as Inception/Resnet/Densenet.

In general, the model zoo here is a good place to start.
https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Model-Zoo

Another place might be this repository which tracks state-of-the-art results on a large variety of datasets -- a large fraction of which are backed by neural networks, so you could look into the various papers for the architectures:
https://github.com/RedditSota/state-of-the-art-result-for-machine-learning-problems